# Persistent/External JQuery Mobile Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, panel

In JQuery Mobile 1.4 panels can be external, fixed and responsive which led me to try to create a persistent sidebar using a panel. Everything seems to work great except that the panel is closed every time a page transitions. The panel is then opened again when the new page is shown.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/egntp/

I would like for the panel to remain on the page during page transition similar to the way persistent toolbars work.

Any ideas? I looked into the panel's beforeClose() event (http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#event-beforeclose) to try to prevent it from closing, but I didn't know how to proceed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.min.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-panel-dismiss{display:none;}
        #p1, #p2{margin-left:17em;}
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){$("#sidebar").panel();});
        $(document).on("pageshow", ":jqmData(role=page)", function() {
            $("#sidebar").panel("open");
        });
    </script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="panel" data-animate="false" data-position-fixed="true" data-swipe-close="false" id="sidebar">
        <h1>sidebar</h1>
        <a href="#p1">Page 1</a><br />
        <a href="#p2">Page 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="p1" data-role="page">
        My page 1
    </div>
    <div id="p2" data-role="page">
        My page 2
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to do similar things, playing around with mild success here and there....try starting with this and see how far you can take it...

```
.ui-panel-closed {
    width: 17em !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

The reason this may work is because all jQuery Mobile is doing when you open or close a panel is they are modifying the css classes of the panel div. One thing they do is toggle a couple css classes, `ui-panel-open` and `ui-panel-closed`.

The above css ensures that even though they add the `ui-panel-closed` class to the panel div, the panel remains open.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in jQuery mobile 1.4 onwards. Just place the panel outside your page (i.e. data-role="page").

Note that external panels need to be initialized manually. So just do the following:

```
$(document).on( "pageshow", "[data-role='page']", function() {
    $( "your_panel_selector" ).panel({ animate: true });
});
```

Comment: This is already what the OP is doing.  So this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This is exactly how I achieved persistent external panel ! Can you explain why you think it doesn't answer the question??

Comment: Because it's already in the question. He's already using an external panel, and he's already initializing it with JavaScript. So clearly this does not answer the question.